# Can I change Macedonian and Albanian money in Serbia? (Belgrade)

Tags: money, exchange, serbia

I am travelling to Serbia tomorrow and I have some Macedonian and Albanian money.

Is possible to Exchange these currencies in Serbia.

Where would i go to exchange these currencies? (I.E. would a regular Bureau De Change be able to do it or would i need to go to a more specialist money changer) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change MKD (denar) banknotes, though IME at piss poor rates. As for ALL (leke), not possible AFAIK.

Unless you know you won't visit Albania/Macedonia in the forseeable future, save that cash for the next visit.

And for the future, don't make the same mistake in Serbia - always change it back to EUR or USD before leaving.

Comment: Thankyou! I will keep in mind ;)